# Can't add domain users to Reporting Services 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dns, ssrs-2008

I have `SSRS 2008` setup on the database server.
The server is part of the domain.
Reporting Services is running under `NetworkService`.
When I try to add a domain user using the web interface (`Site Settings` --> `Security` --> `New Role Assignment`), the page posts back but the user is not in the list.
The server's log file contains the following Unhandled Exception:

> ui!ReportManager_0-1!954!01/12/2009-10:14:52:: Unhandled exception:
>   System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all
>   identity references could not be translated.    at
>   System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection
>   sourceSids, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)    at
>   System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(Type
>   targetType)    at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName() 
>   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name()    at
>   ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.RsWorkerRequest.GetServerVariable(String
>   name)    at
>   System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule.OnEnter(Object source,
>   EventArgs eventArgs)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Any one have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

got to home then on properties
and then add the user with roles whatever you want to gives.

Answer (score 0):

Are there other domain users in the list of allowed users? Perhaps "NetworkService" doesn't have rights to read from AD, though I would expect it to. I've always run SSRS as a domain proxy user (Domain\SSRS_Proxy, or whatever), and I've been able to add "Domain Users" before.

Comment: I actually ended up rebuilding the server.  I never could figure out what was going on with it.